# cargo-contract throws on a valid WS URl

Tags: smart-contract, cargo-contract

Most recent version (v1.3.0) of cargo-contract does not parse a valid WS url:

```bash
cargo +nightly contract upload --suri '//Alice' --url 'wss://ws-smartnet.test.azero.dev:443'
```

```bash
ERROR: Rpc error: Networking or low-level protocol error: Invalid URL: No port number in URL (default port is not supported)

Caused by:
    0: Networking or low-level protocol error: Invalid URL: No port number in URL (default port is not supported)
    1: Invalid URL: No port number in URL (default port is not supported)
```

Connecting with wscat proceeds as expected:

```
wscat -c wss://ws-smartnet.test.azero.dev:443 -p 13
Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this issue has been resolved upstream. Should no longer be a problem when released.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by a peculiar behavior of Rust `url` library, which insists to store port as `None` in case that is the default port for a particular protocol. This is your case (443 for wss)

`cargo-contract` uses `url` to parse the command line argument to `url::Url` and then converts it back to `String` while passing to `subxt::ClientBuilder`. That string -> url -> string conversion results in the port value being lost in case the default port was used. This is a bug in `cargo-contract`.

Comment: Have you considered opening an issue there or a PR to correct? https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract

Comment: I already did https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/587